# Is the theme that the Github.blog site uses available to download?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jekyll, github-pages, hugo, static-site

I really like the theme of the Github blog (http://github.blog), and I'm wondering if the theme is available for use on other sites. I thought about finding out the name of the theme, which you could do with wordpress sites (for example, using a theme finder like whatwpthemeisthat). But I couldn't find a jekyll theme detector and therefore can't find the name of the theme that way.

I next searched the github libraries for "github blog theme", as I'm assuming that's the name of the theme, but as you would expect I was bombarded with static site themes (like Jekyll, hugo, bootstrap) that work with gh-pages. So I went onto the github company profile, and searched through their repositories, but couldn't find it either.

Is it a private theme, or does it not work with static sites?

Comment: The theme looks to be made by https://10up.com/ according to their default stylesheet: https://github.blog/wp-content/themes/github-blog/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can find one similar used with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) (a static website generator)

[**themes.gohugo.io/github-style**](https://themes.gohugo.io/github-style/)

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/5ab714d704752698669a304e36b4af1772c8d73f/795c7/github-style/screenshot-github-style_hu8fd5979415d309ffffa537b9d823e1c2_209006_1500x1000_fill_catmullrom_top_2.png]

Even if you are not using Hugo, you can still check out its [theme CSS](https://github.com/MeiK2333/github-style/tree/master/static/css).

Comment: Hey thanks, but I was asking about the github blog theme - http://github.blog

Comment: @LiamArbuckle What I mention is used for blogs and based on GitHub: you will get a look that can be adapted to be similar to GitHub blogs.